# How to connect mule repository?

Tags: maven, repository, mule

I'm getting below when i run my mule interface.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project apl-integration: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.katalystm:apl-integration:mule:1.0.0-PRE: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.7.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.7.0:

Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:pom:3.7.0 from/to mulesoft-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/): Connect to repository.mulesoft.org:80 [repository.mulesoft.org/52.7.200.18] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

Seem it is failed to connect the http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/, i have added the repository even in my POM file aslo.

```
<repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
           <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
           <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
           <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this repository

```
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
        <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
        <url>
         https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
        </url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

Comment: May be you are bounded with a office/home-pc firewall. Try to build the mule project apart from anypoint studio. Try with a different internet connection.